# How can I replace a particular character with its upper-case counterpart?

Tags: perl

Consider the following string

String = **"this is for test. i'm new to perl! Please help. can u help? i hope so."**

In the above string after `.` or `?` or `!` the next character should be in upper case. how can I do that?

I'm reading from text file line by line and I need to write modified data to another file.

your help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you could use a regular expression
try this:

```
my $s = "...";
$s =~ s/([\.\?!]\s*[a-z])/uc($1)/ge; # of course $1 , thanks to plusplus
```

the g-flag searches for all matches and the e-flag executes uc to convert the letter to uppercase

Explanation:

- with [.\?!] you search for your punctuation marks
- \s* is for whitespaces between the marks and the first letter of your next word and
- [a-z] matches on a single letter (in this case the first one of the next word

the regular expression mentioned above searches with these patterns for every appearance of a punctuation mark followed by (optional) whitespaces and a letter and replaces it with the result of uc (which converts the match to uppercase).

For example:

```
my $s = "this is for test. i'm new to perl! Please help. can u help? i hope so.";
$s =~ s/([\.\?!]\s*[a-z])/uc(&1)/ge;
print $s;
```

will find ". i", "! P", ". c" and "? i" and replaces then, so the printed result is:

```
this is for test. I'm new to perl! Please help. Can u help? I hope so.
```

Comment: thanx for your replay but i'm not getting can you give one example please.

Comment: it should be `$1` not `&1` in the `uc()`

Comment: It's implied in the help test that you yourself quoted :-)

Comment: No need to use /e and uc(), use \u, as in this:  s/([.?!]\s*)(\w)/$1\u$2/g

Comment: How to add a space inside of the substitution part? ` uc($1)` replaces with `uc($1)`, the space is ignored

Answer (score 2):

You can use the substitution operator `s///`:

```
   $string =~ s/([.?!]\s*\S)/ uc($1) /ge;
```

Comment: This answer could stand to have some commentary, especially considering that the OP is new to Perl.

Comment: @nathan The OP does not actually say that he is new to perl, it's only the text in his example string.

Comment: @TLP: He wrote it in the example text.

Comment: hey guys if you are talking about me. Yes i'm new to perl as i said in det example.

Comment: @banadishrs I was just pointing out to Nathan that there was a built-in ambiguity to your statement. It has nothing to do with what you *really* meant. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `split` solution:

```
$str = "this is for test. im new to perl! Please help. can u help? i hope so."; 
say join "", map ucfirst, split /([?!.]\s*)/, $str;
```

If all you are doing is printing to a new file, you don't need to join the string back up. E.g.

```
while ($line = <$input>) {
    print $output map ucfirst, split /([?!.]\s*)/, $line;
}
```

Comment: you need the regular expression to split ;)

Comment: @Hachi Oh, I see what you mean. Yes, I suppose I dropped the ball there.

Answer (score 0):

edit - completely misread the question, thought you were just asking to uppercase the `i`s for some reason, apologies for any confusion!

as the answers so far state, you could look at regular expressions, and the substitution operator `(s///)`. No-one has mentioned the `\b` (word boundary) character though, which may be useful to find the single `i`s - otherwise you are going to have to keep adding punctuation characters that you find to the character class match (the `[ ... ]`).

e.g.

```
my $x = "this is for test. i'm new to perl! Please help. can u help? i hope so. ".
       \"i want it to work!\". Dave, Bob, Henry viii and i are friends. foo i bar.";

$x =~ s/\bi\b/I/g;  # or could use the capture () and uc($1) in eugene's answer
```

gives:

```
# this is for test. I'm new to perl! Please help. can u help? I hope so. 
# "I want it to work!". Dave, Bob, Henry viii and I are friends. foo I bar.
```