# In Perl (simple program for newbie needed) , after . or ? or ! the next character should be in upper case

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I replace a particular character with its upper-case counterpart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753950/how-can-i-replace-a-particular-character-with-its-upper-case-counterpart)

Consider following string :

```
String = "this is for test. i'm new to perl! Please help. can u help? i hope so."
```

In the above string, after . or ? or ! the next character should be in upper case. Also the first letter of the sentence (string) is to be in uppercase. How can I do that?
I'm reading string character by character.

your help will be greatly appreciated.

regards,
Amit

Answer (score 4):

In a basic way, you can try this code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$String = "this is for test. i'm new to perl! Please help. can u help? i hope so.";
$String =~ s/ ((^\w)|(\.\s\w)|(\?\s\w)|(\!\s\w))/\U$1/xg;
print "$String\n";
```

`(^\w)` : beginning of the line
`(\.\s\w)` : After a '.' followed by a space
`(\?\s\w)` : After a '?' followed by a space
`(\!\s\w)` : After a '!' followed by a space

Answer (score 2):

Perl has a [`ucfirst`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ucfirst.html) function that does exactly what you want. So all you need to do it to split your string into sections, use `ucfirst` on each section and then join them together again.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use 5.010;

my $string = q[this is for test. i'm new to perl! Please help. can u help? i hope so.];

my @bits = split /([.?!]\s+)/, $string;

$string = join '', map { ucfirst } @bits;

say $string;
```

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use File::Slurp;
use File::Slurp qw( :all );

open (In_FILE, 'matter.txt') || die("Could not open file!");
my $F1 = read_file('matter.txt');
$F1=ucfirst($F1);
print "$F1\n";
my $F2 =~ s/([\.\?!]\s*[a-z])/uc(&1)/ge;
my $F3 = write_file('copy_matter.txt', $F1);
write_file('copy_matter_1.txt', $F2);
close(In_FILE) || die("Could not close file!!");                                                                  QUESTION IS : WHY "$F2" doesnt work?